# How to use return value from a function and use it in the next function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use the first function's value to apply on the second function that I am defining.

I defined `collectUserInputTime()` which takes no argument.

Once I called `collectUserInputTime()`, it does not change the value of `startHour` and `startMinute`.

Also, if I don't define `startHour` and `startMinute` outside of functions, I will get a `startHour` and `startMinute` undefine.

I also tried to add print(`startHour`)inside of `collectUserInputTime()`, it did print out my input(), but it does not change the `startHour` outside of the function. `startHour` still remain as an empty string.

```
startHour = ''
startMinute = ''
def collectUserInputTime():
     print('Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation:')
     data = input()
     astop = data.find(':')
     startHour = data[0:astop]
     startMinute = data[astop+1:]
     return startHour and startMinute



def validateUserInputTime(startHour , startMinute):
    if (startHour in hoursList and startMinute in minutesList):
        print('it is valid')
    else:
        print('input invalid')

collectUserInputTime()
validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)
```

How am I able to use the return value from `collectUserInputTime()` which are `startHour` and `startMinute`? Eventually, I can validate in my function `validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)`

Comment: `ret_val = collectUserInputTime()` and perhaps  `validateUserInputTime(ret_val[0], ret_val[1])`

Comment: Make the return a tuple like `return startHour, startMinute` instead of `return startHour and startMinute`. The latter will return a boolean and it will certainly be True in your case :). And get the values as `startHour, StartMinute = collectUserInputTime()`  and apply it `validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)`

Comment: are `hoursList` and `minutesList` global variables?

Comment: `hoursList` and `minutesList` is global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startHour = ''
startMinute = ''
def collectUserInputTime():
     print('Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation:')
     data = input()
     astop = data.find(':')
     startHour = data[0:astop]
     startMinute = data[astop+1:]
     print(startHour)
     print(startMinute)
     return startHour, startMinute

ret_val = collectUserInputTime()
print("Hours: ", ret_val[0])
print("Minutes: ", ret_val[1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
13:54
13
54
Hours:  13
Minutes:  54
```

and so you can use it in your `validateUserInputTime(startHour , startMinute)`:

```
def validateUserInputTime(startHour , startMinute):
    if (startHour in hoursList and startMinute in minutesList):
        print('it is valid')
    else:
        print('input invalid')

ret_val = collectUserInputTime()
startHour = ret_val[0]
startMinute = ret_val[1]
validateUserInputTime(startHour, startMinute)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would change what the function collectUserInputTime() returns. I would use a list!

Then I would use a CS concept called "Helper function": in short, you can call a function within another function.

The code is the following

```
def collectUserInputTime():
 data = input('Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation: ')
 astop = data.find(':')
 startHour = data[0:astop]
 startMinute = data[astop+1:]
 return [startHour, startMinute]

def validateUserInputTime():
 hour = collectUserInputTime()
 startHour, startMinute = int(hour[0]), int(hour[1]) # if lists are int_lists
 if (startHour in hoursList) and (startMinute in minutesList):
     print('It is valid')
 else:
     print('Input invalid')
```

I have also made the code more "Pythonic" in few lines!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```py
startHour = ''
startMinute = ''
def collectUserInputTime():
     print('Enter the time the call starts in 24-hour rotation:')
     data = input()
     astop = data.find(':')
     startHour = data[0:astop]
     startMinute = data[astop+1:]
     return (startHour, startMinute)



def validateUserInputTime(startHour , startMinute):
    if (startHour in hoursList and startMinute in minutesList):
        print('it is valid')
    else:
        print('input invalid')

rtn_data = collectUserInputTime()
validateUserInputTime(rtn_data[0], rtn_data[1])
```